# RHEL7 join to AD using Ansible

Tags: active-directory, ansible, rhel7

Looking into the best practice way of joining a RHEL7 to AD using Ansible.  Is there an [ansible module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_all_modules.html) to do this?  I had a look but there doesn't appear to be.

This article "[How to join RHEL system to Active Directory domain using adcli](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2653771)" from Redhat seems like the way to go, but is it the best method to use when implemening with Ansible using the [command module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/command_module.html)?

If the above is the best way, is there a way to ensure idempotence?  The command module has a option called `creates` but this doesn't seem like the most eloquent way.

Thanks for any pointers/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [ansible role](https://github.com/mGageTechOps/ansible-role-authconfig-ad/blob/master/tasks/redhat.yml#L12). Using the `command` or `shell` module seems to be best option. In the linked repository you can find examples for the `creates` parameter. Which is the common way to ensure idempotence.